# Flow: expect imported css file to be a string

Tags: javascript, webpack, flowtype

I'm using webpack to import css files as strings, with the following loader configuration

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loaders: [{
    loader: 'to-string-loader'
  }, {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      minimize: true
    }
  }]
}
```

But then when I import the css string

```
import css from './styles.css'
```

Flow complains with this error message

`Flow assumes requiring a .css file returns an Object. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of string`

What can I do to override this assumption and make flow expect a `string` from a css import?

*To clarify, I would like flow to type check the import strictly as a `string`, as opposed to ignoring the error / expecting `any` or some other workaround.*

Answer (score 0):

For now I have settled with a rather ugly, but straightforward solution.

I create a normal js module `css.js`, not Flow type checked, to use as a proxy for the css strings

```
import styles from './styles.css'

export default { styles }
```

Then I import `css.js` from another Flow type checked file, and the types work as expected

```
// @flow
import css from './css.js'

function expectsString (arg: string) {...}

expectsString(css.styles) // no Flow warnings here
```

As I say, I'm not that happy with this solution, but it's at least self-contained and easy to understand, and it fulfils the requirement.